# Fiddle out columns in python to save in variables

Tags: python, csv

I was trying to get the two colums from a variable that I had from a previous code,

Lets say the example from the variable I got (it is nordic format and seismic saff) this is the variable called data.

> ```
> STAT    SP  IPHASW  D   HRMM    SECON   CODA    AMPLIT  PERI    AZIMU   VELO    AIN AR  TRES    W   DIS CAZ7  
> PB11    BZ  IP      D   6 9     31.76   62                                              -0.4810     350 221   
> PB11    SZ  IAML        610     18.65           486.2   1.70                                        350 221   
> PB08    BZ  IP      C   6 9     39.09   62      6.2310                                              353 210   
> PB08    SZ  IAML        610     30.80            232.5  1.80                                        353 210   
> PSGCX   BZ  IP      D   6 9     31.60   62      -3.9110                                             372 228   
> PSGCX   SZ  IAML        610     55.47           317.5   2.50                                        372 228   
> PB01    BZ  IP      D   6 9     46.54   62      -1.70           9                                   457 207   
> PB01    SZ  IAML        611     7.26            160.1   3.10                                        457 207   
> MOCB    SZ  IP      C   6 9     48.34   62      -2.06           9                                   470 156   
> PB09    BZ  IP      C   610     9.79    62      11.72           9                                   523 200   
> PB09    SZ  IAML        611     51.60           478.4   3.00
> ```

The target variable are HRMM SECON (hour Minite Senond), that generally are from the 19 to 29 position.

I wanted to separate the Hours in a variable called H, the minutes in a variable called M and the seconsds in a avariable called S, something like this

> H=[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,...] Min=[9, 10, 9, 10, 10, 11,....]
>   Seconds=[31.66,18.55,....]

I tryed to do this code,

```
oo=[]
for line in data:
    parte=line.split('\n')
    limp=parte[0]
    print limp
    for linne in limp:
        linne=limp.strip()
        oo.append(linne[19:29].split('\n'))
    print oo
```

But unfortanatelly I am not able to get like this. I got like this.

```
00=[6 9 31.33, 6 9 31.33, 6 9 31.33, 6 9 31.33, ......]
```

Many times the same, always the same number and no separate as I showed you.

I tryied to modifie the code like this.

```
for line in data:
    parte=line.split('\n')
    if len(parte) > 1:
        #print parte[0]
        for lline in parte:
            partes=lline.strip('')
            partes=lline.split('/t')
            print partes
```

and I got it:

> [' STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES
>   W  DIS CAZ7']
>
> ['']
>
> [' PB11 BZ IP     D  6 9 31.76                              62
>   -0.4810  350 221 ']
>
> ['']
>
> [' PB11 SZ  IAML     610 18.65       486.2 1.70
>   350 221 ']
>
> ['']
>
> [' PB08 BZ IP     C  6 9 39.09                              62
>   6.2310  353 210 ']
>
> ['']

Can you give a hand?, thank you a lot for the time

Tonino

Dear all, I found a solution and I'd like to know if it is a pythonic way to do it, please feel free to comment

```
indexStat=0
HMS=[]
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i].find("STAT ")>=0:
        indexStat=i
        break
    for j in range(indexStat+1,len(data)):
        ll=data[j]
        res=(ll[18:29])
        print res
```

These lines let me to get the data from HRMM SECON, i had no change to count places to get them, does any one have a better idea, it works, but i am  sure that there is a pythonic way to do it.

Thank you  a lot.

Tonino

Comment: Why is `HRMM` sometimes one column and sometimes two?  It looks like part of your problem is your data isn't consistently formatted.  I would recommend looking into the `csv` module for handling data like this.

Comment: Dear @PatrickHaugh , it is because the HR represents the hour in GMT from 00 to 23, MM represents the minutes from 00 to 59, and the data inside are the times of P or S picks, and thanks for the module name.